# How to remove emojies(smiles) with space?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my string I want to replace emojies with a space so that I can find correct index of characters. This is because with emojies the string length is different.

Is there any way to remove all emojie characters with a space in swift 2.3?

Comment: > `because with emojies the string length is diffrent`. Can you explain this? And paste your code counting characters.

Comment: this will help you https://github.com/woxtu/NSString-RemoveEmoji

Comment: Swift is the only the only programming language I know that correctly handles Unicode and doesn't confuse characters, codepoints, UTF-16 words and UTF-8 bytes. Please read [Ole Begemann's blog on Strings](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/) to understand the difference. Replacing emojies with spaces sound like the wrong thing to do.

Comment: my string is  = "helllo  :) :( (some smiles) @jacky what s up #ri7".....and i want to find index of @.  so i am getting wrong index because of smiles take utf-8(#242423) code so more than 5 charcter count......so i am getting wrong index .so is there is any way to take smiley as only one character only